# How to find all the possible continuous functions $g(x)$ such that $f(x)g(x)=k$ by maintaining the $x$ dependence of $f(x)g(x)$?

Tags: analysis, functions

As the title says the goal is to find all the possible continuous functions $g(x)$ in the domain $D_g$ such that $f(x)g(x)=k$, where $f(x)$ is continuos in $D_f$ and $k\in\mathbb{R}$, by maintaining the $x$ dependance on the left side of the equation. With maintaining the $x$ dependence I mean that for one or more, but still finite, specific values of $x$ the LHS is equal to the RHS, but not for all $x$ in the domain of $f(x)g(x)$.

In order to maintain the $x$ dependence for the product of the two functions I can't simply divide both sides for $f(x)$, obtaining $g(x)=\frac{k}{f(x)}$.

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949149/how-to-find-a-function-fx-such-that-lim-x-to-inftyi-sqrt1-x2fx-1) on a similar subject that I asked, @[qbert](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210391/qbert) in a comment on his answer wrote that there are many functions of this kind that I can choose. The question is, is there a method to find all the possible $g(x)$? If not what should I do to find them?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "$x$-dependence". If the RHS is constant, then so will be the LHS.

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll edit the question, for a specific value of $x$ the LHS is equal to the RHS but not in all of it's domain.

Comment: Would you like it to hold for only finitely many values of $x$? Countably? Uncountably?

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense.  If $f(x)g(x) = k$ and $k$ is constant then either $k \ne 0$ and so $f(x)$ is never $0$ and $g(x) = \frac k{f(x)}$ or $k = 0$ so so $g(x) = 0$ when $f(x)\ne 0$ and $g(x)$ can be anything where $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Sobi Finite, sorry if I've to make all those specifications after the original question, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not give a method to find *all* such functions, but it provides a wide spectrum of functions which satisfy the wanted property, so it might be helpful.

Let $f$ be a continuous function which is non-zero at all points (since we will want to divide by it).

We want to find a continuous function $g$ such that $f(x)g(x) = k$, for some finite number of values of $x$, which we denote by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Let $h(x)$ be any continuous function, and define
$$ g(x) = \frac{k}{f(x)}+h(x)\prod_{j=1}^n (x-x_j). $$

Clearly, this is a continuous function, and $g(x_j) = \frac{k}{f(x_j)}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$, so that
$$ f(x_j)g(x_j) = k, $$
on our finite set of points, but in general,
$$ f(x)g(x) = k + f(x)h(x)\prod_{j=1}^n (x-x_j). $$

Just to show that not all functions need to be of this form, consider $f(x) = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and suppose we want to find a $g$ such that $f(x)g(x)=1$. Then $g(x) = \overline{f(x)}$ is an obvious choice, since
$$ f(x) \overline{f(x)} = |f(x)|^2 = \cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x) = 1, $$
and this in fact holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It certainly is helpful, thanks.